# SQL Logic on union results. If same ID, date, time in Table A and Table B use Table B and

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic, case, union

I am working on a query (Results will be exported to another vendor) I discovered that I can not have 2 different transaction types at the same date and time for the same ID. If there is a conflict I need to have the logic pass from Result B the ID, Date, Time, Labor Code, Type of 'Punch In' and ignore the conflict of Results A

Current Code:

```
select 
    E.idnum, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), at.DTTMSTAMP, 111) as 'date', 
    at.DTTMSTAMP,
    '',
    '',
    CASE when (select Count (*) from ARCHIVES A1, ARCTRANSACTIONS AT1 where at1.ownerid = a1.UNIQUEID and a1.eventdate =a.EVENTDATE and a1.FILEKEY = a.filekey and at.DTTMSTAMP <= at1.DTTMSTAMP)%2 =0 then 'In Punch' Else 'Out Punch' End as 'Type'  ,
    '' 
from ARCHIVES A, ARCTRANSACTIONS AT, Employees E 
where E.filekey = at.FILEKEY and at.ownerid = a.UNIQUEID and a.eventdate between '2020-06-21' and '2020-06-27'

UNION

select 
    E.IDNUM,
    s.EVENTDATE as 'date',
    s.STARTTIME,
    '/'+WG5.code+'///'+WG4.CODE+'//'+WG6.CODE,
    '',
    'Transfer',
    ''  
from WORKGROUPTRANS S, Employees E, WORKGROUP1 wg1, WORKGROUP2 wg2,WORKGROUP3 wg3, WORKGROUP4 wg4, WORKGROUP5 wg5, WORKGROUP6 wg6  
where EVENTDATE between '2020-06-21' and '2020-06-27' and e.filekey = s.FILEKEY and wg1.WGNUM = s.WG1 and wg2.WGNUM = s.WG2 and wg3.WGNUM = s.WG3 and wg4.WGNUM = s.WG4 and wg5.WGNUM = s.WG5 and wg6.WGNUM = s.WG6

order by 1,2,3,4
```

[image: Picture of Current Results]

Comment: Result B is the "Transfer" (highlighted in the picture) Results A are those labeled "Punch In" and "Punch Out". I want to ignore the matching ID / DATE / TIME of the conflicting "Punch In" and rename the Type of the conflicting "Transfer" to "Punch In".

Comment: Thanks @Dale K for the edits it looks more professional now. Way to keep the archive neat and tidy. Thanks again. If you think you can help with the answer I would also like that too.

Comment: If you add some test data as DDL/DML (i.e. create temp table + insert) which will allow me to run your query I will have a look at it. You want to make it as easy as possible for people to help, so if they can copy and paste a bunch of SQL for immediate testing thats easy :)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested query, probably containing typos:

```
;with a as (
    select 
        E.idnum, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), at.DTTMSTAMP, 111) as 'date', 
        at.DTTMSTAMP,
        '' Code,
        '' Col1,
        CASE when (select Count (*) from ARCHIVES A1, ARCTRANSACTIONS AT1 where at1.ownerid = a1.UNIQUEID and a1.eventdate =a.EVENTDATE and a1.FILEKEY = a.filekey and at.DTTMSTAMP <= at1.DTTMSTAMP)%2 =0 then 'In Punch' Else 'Out Punch' End as 'Type'  ,
        '' Col2
    from ARCHIVES A, ARCTRANSACTIONS AT, Employees E 
    where E.filekey = at.FILEKEY and at.ownerid = a.UNIQUEID and a.eventdate between '2020-06-21' and '2020-06-27'
),
b as (
    select 
        E.IDNUM,
        s.EVENTDATE as 'date',
        s.STARTTIME,
        '/'+WG5.code+'///'+WG4.CODE+'//'+WG6.CODE as Code,
        '',
        'Transfer' as Type,
        ''  
    from WORKGROUPTRANS S, Employees E, WORKGROUP1 wg1, WORKGROUP2 wg2,WORKGROUP3 wg3, WORKGROUP4 wg4, WORKGROUP5 wg5, WORKGROUP6 wg6  
    where EVENTDATE between '2020-06-21' and '2020-06-27' and e.filekey = s.FILEKEY and wg1.WGNUM = s.WG1 and wg2.WGNUM = s.WG2 and wg3.WGNUM = s.WG3 and wg4.WGNUM = s.WG4 and wg5.WGNUM = s.WG5 and wg6.WGNUM = s.WG6
)
select a.idnum, a.date, a.DTTMSTAMP, 
    isnull(b.Code,'' as )Code, a.Col1, 
    case when b.Type is not null then 'In Punch' else a.Type end as Type, 
    a.Col2
from a
left join b on b.idnum=a.idnum and b.STARTTIME=a.DTTMSTAMP
union
select * from b
where not exists(select * from a where a.idnum=b.idnum and a.DTTMSTAMP=b.STARTTIME)
order by 1,2,3,4
```